# Selenium IDE table column sum

Tags: html, selenium, selenium-ide

I have a table with a column that contains only financial values (positive and negative numbers).

I need to sum all the values of the column with Selenium IDE, and compare with the total shown in the table...

I'm clueless! I'm totally new to Selenium.

Note: the table doesn't have any id, CSS, etc. (it's from an old/simple site), but the values are dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get all of those values.  Personally i'd delegate this task to JavaScript.  You could do something like this:

```
storeEval | var sum=0;var rows=document.getElementsByTagName('td');for(var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {sum += rows[i].innerHTML;} return sum; | myVariable
```